# Vue: Can't dynamically insert value from function

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have data, `timestamp`, that comes from the server as a unix timestamp.  I am trying to dynamically insert this in every second.  I can get it to successfully console.log the time (console.log(x)) but it won't return it and insert the time in the DOM.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span> {{ checkItemExpiry(timestamp) }}</span>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            convertTime: function(time) {
                var sec_num = parseInt(time, 10);
                var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
                var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
                var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

                if (hours < 10) {
                    hours = "0" + hours;
                }
                if (minutes < 10) {
                    minutes = "0" + minutes;
                }
                if (seconds < 10) {
                    seconds = "0" + seconds;
                }

                let x = (hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
                console.log(x)
                return x
            },

            checkItemExpiry: function(expireTimestamp) {
                let startTime = expireTimestamp;

                setInterval(() => {
                    let currentTime = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
                    this.convertTime((startTime-currentTime))
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    }


</script>
```

Comment: checkItemExpiry has no return value, try using data and modify the value of data instead

Comment: Calling methods from your template is generally a bad idea. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods

Comment: You might need to use [computed property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example)